# Can you generate dynamic and multiple conditions for grep?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have some JSON data I want to filter with a few dropdowns.  Not all the dropdowns will be populated and because of this when I run the grep below it doesn't return all the results I want.

First I'm putting the selected value of each dropdown in a variable.  If the first index is selected the variable is null.  Then I'm filtering, but if any of the variables are null (meaning the dropdown wasn't changed) it passes a null value into the grep condition, thus not returning correct data.  Is there a way to generate my multiple conditions based on the variables being null?  I know I could do nested after nested if statements but that doesn't seem efficient.

```
var selectedVoltage     = ($selectVoltage[0].selectedIndex > 0) ? $selectVoltage.val() : null;
var selectedMaxLPA      = ($selectMaxLPA[0].selectedIndex > 0)  ? $selectMaxLPA.val() : null;
var selectedFluidLevel  = ($selectFluidLevel[0].selectedIndex > 0) ? $selectFluidLevel.val(): null;

var filtered = $.grep(json ,function(product) {
        return product.voltage === selectedVoltage && 
               product.lpa <= selectedMaxLPA   && 
               product.fluid_level <= selectedFluidLevel;
               //is it possible to dynamically generate these conditions?
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test whether the variable is set and only do the comparison if it is:

```
var filtered = $.grep(json ,function(product) {
    return (selectedVoltage === '' || selectedVoltage === null || product.voltage === selectedVoltage) && 
            (selectedMaxLPA === '' || selectedMaxLPA === null || product.lpa <= selectedMaxLPA)   && 
            (selectedFluidLevel === '' || selectedFluidLevel === null || product.fluid_level <= selectedFluidLevel);
            //is it possible to dynamically generate these conditions?
});
```

Comment: I did exactly that, however if I only pick a value for Voltage it returns no results.  it should return everything that has the voltage I picked without filtering for the other two fields.

Comment: I've added code to test for `null` in addition to empty strings.

Comment: Ahhh you are absolutely right!  It's a string so changing it from null to an empty `''` worked.   Thank you!!